# Pandora Radio Client

Tags: server, mediaserver, pandora

I am fairly new to the Linux community. I apologize in advance if this question has been asked & answered already.

I have a fairly large mp3 collection and am looking for a Linux based media player. While I have found a number of them, I am looking for a server similar to Pandora Radio that has the following specific features:

1. Stations - creating a Nine Inch Nails Station will make the server automatically play music similar to NIN,
2. Accessible from Windows, Linux and Android clients,
3. Multi-user - Allowing each member of my household to create their own stations.

Again, I apologize in advance if this has been asked & answered. I've been looking, but haven't found anything, which could be due to my lack of Linux knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Logitech Media Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logitech_Media_Server).

This is software that used to be bundled with Logitech hardware that is now obsolete, but it is still being maintained and developed. You can find it [here](http://downloads.slimdevices.com/nightly/?ver=7.9). Download the "Debian Installer Package" that corresponds with your computer architecture (ARM, i386 32bits, AMD 64 bits) and install it with `dpkg -i logitechmediaserver-[version].deb`. Currently, the latest version is 7.9.
After installing it, you point it at your mp3 collection and it will create a database of your mp3 collection. You control it through a small webserver running on port 9000. There are various apps in the Apple Store and the Google Play store to control it.

I have been running this server for years on various pieces of hardware, either on a Ubuntu server or Raspberry Pi (running Raspbian). It's a very solid piece of work. It comes with many plugins, including (yes!) Spotify.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try! My girlfriend hates building playlists (via my Plex Media Server) so finding a media server with the "station" feature is my current quest.