# Music Server - Pandora/Spotify Clone

Tags: server, music

I am currently running Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (Xenial Xerus) 64-bit on a Intel Core i5-4590 Quad-core 3.30GHz CPU with a drive that has over 94,000 songs in mp3 & flac formats. My family includes 7 other people, including 4 teenagers.

I'm not a big fan of them letting the teenagers plug their device into my server to transfer music, so I would like to find a Linux based music server that will support multiple users (via account creation) and allow users to create their own radio stations by selecting an artist or song, and by giving a thumb-up or thumb-down to played songs. The server would then respond by playing more of what the user likes based off these inputs.

(the ability to access via mobile device would be awesome, but not 100% necessary)

Based on an answer to my original posting ([Pandora Radio Client](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763296/pandora-radio-client)), I tried Logitech Media Server and The Music Player Daemon, but didn't find exactly what I am looking for (or in the case of Logitech Media Server, I couldn't get it to work -- which could be due to my lack of Linux knowledge and/or experience).

Wondering if anybody has suggestions.

Comment: I'm still a huge fan of the Logitech Media Server, so if there's anything I can do to help you get it to work, I'd be happy to.

Comment: I appreciate the offer. I am currently putting together another machine that I will try LMS on. I'm worried that Plex Media Server and LMS may have conflicted with each other and that's why I had issues getting it to work. I will for sure hit you up when I get to installing LMS.

Also, I have been unable to find an answer to my question about LMS, does it offer the features I mentioned above (multiuser and playing music based on users likes/dislikes)?

Comment: So I installed LMS with the following commands:  

wget http://downloads.slimdevices.com/LogitechMediaServer_v7.8.0/logitechmediaserver_7.8.0_all.deb  
sudo dpkg --install logitechmediaserver_7.8.0_all.deb  

After the install completed, I opened a terminal window and typed:  
sudo service squeezeboxserver start

And got this message  
Failed to start squeezeboxserver.service: Unit squeezeboxserver.service not found.

Comment: The name of the service is `logitechmediaserver`. However, it may already be running: try `systemctl status logitechmediaserver` first.